# Integration over a manifold with boundary (Check).

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

> Assume that $ f: \Bbb{R}^{3} \to \Bbb{R} $ is a smooth function such that $ M \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \left\{ \mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{3} ~ \middle| ~ f(\mathbf{x}) \ge 0 \right\} $ is a non-empty compact $ 3 $-dimensional manifold with boundary. Prove that for $ g = f^{2} $, we have
>   $$
> \int_{M} \nabla g ~ \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{x}} = 0,
> $$
>   where $ \displaystyle {\nabla g}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} (\partial_{i,i} g)(\mathbf{x}) $ for all $ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $.

I plugged $ \displaystyle \nabla g = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} \partial_{i,i} g $ and $ g = f^{2} $ into the integral to get
$$
\int_{M}
\left( \partial_{1,1} f^{2} + \partial_{2,2} f^{2} + \partial_{3,3} f^{2} \right)
\mathrm{d}{\mathbf{x}}.
$$
How should I proceed further from this? Any methodological help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I attempted a solution. I am trying to write the Laplacian as divergence

$\int_M\nabla g=\int_M\partial_1g+\partial_2g+\partial_3g= \int_M \partial_1f^2+ \partial_2f^2+\partial_3f^2=\int_ \partial f^2+f^2+f^2=3\int_\partial f^2=3\cdot (\frac{f^3}{3}) $

Now, I think $(\frac{f^3}{3})=0$ because the integral is evaluated on the boundary and on the boundary, f attains $0$. $\partial$ index of the integral means the boundary of $M$

Is this true?

Comment: What is the notation $D_{i,i}$?

Comment: If $\nabla$ is supposed to be the Laplacian, then you should use Stoke's theorem.

Comment: Can you please help me with it? @user225318 I can't do it

Comment: Do you know the statement of Stokes' theorem (or the divergence theorem)? If not, look it up. If yes, try to write the Laplacian as a divergence.

Comment: @user225318 doesn't come out

Comment: This is really horrid notation. Please write either $\nabla^2 g$ (as most math and physics texts do) or $\Delta g$ (as most research-level math texts do).

Comment: The question was given that way @TedShifrin

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't come out?" If you tried something and got stuck somewhere, please edit your attempt into your question.

Comment: @user225318 I have updated

Comment: You really should change your notation. In any event, in physicist's otation:

$$\nabla^2 g = \nabla \cdot (\nabla g)\quad\text{ and }\quad
\nabla g = 2 f \nabla f = 0\;\text{ on the boundary }\; \partial M
$$

Comment: @user225318 I attempted a solution can you please take a look and comment on it?

Comment: What you wrote in your edit is false, as it does not agree with your own definition earlier!

Comment: How should I do it then? @user225318